# How to secretly hide a git commit

Tags: git, github

Is there anyway to undo/ delete a git push and hide the content from commit message? I know how to do a git revert HEAD, but that still shows the pushed code before, any better way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Find hash string of a specific commit at your prefer point, for example `18f747d`.
Use

```
git reset --hard 18f747d
git push --force
```